# Bot read from my api endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, wit.ai, dialogflow-es

I am creating a bot on facebook messenger, following the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation)

Is there a way for the bot to retrieve results from my own api endpoint?

Essentially, I have set up an api endpoint from which results in json is to be returned. I would like the results to populate the template in facebook messenger, like how the current [CNN messenger bot shows news based on queries](https://messengerplatform.fb.com/)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot can do anything you want from him. But you have to setup him first on your server...

What he will return, or his behaviour is up to you.

You can use PHP with my API: https://github.com/Fritak/messenger-platform

Just follow an example and then return generic template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API.ai to create chatbots on Facebook messenger pretty easily. Full disclosure = yes I work there. We've had great feedback on our FB Messenger integration as well as Slack, Kik, Telegram, Twilio SMS, etc.  https://docs.api.ai/docs/facebook-integration